# Trouble with Replacement for base case of recursive function

Tags: replacement, recursion

I have defined a recursive function `W[g_,n_]`, with the base case values `W[0,3]` and `W[1,1]`.

Now I want to total `W[g,n]` for fixed values of `2g-2+n`, which I do like so:

```
pairs[k_] := Solve[2 g - 2 + n == k && g >= 0 && n > 0, {g, n}, Integers]

S[m_]:= Total[W[g, n] /. pairs[m - 1]]
```

This seems to be working, except when I compute `S[2]`, which should be `W[1,1]+W[0,3]`. Instead I get zero.

I see that both

```
W[g, n] /. {g -> 0, n -> 3}
W[g, n] /. {g -> 1, n -> 1}
```

give me zero, when I have defined these values, and they are not zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `S[m]` isn't well defined. The function `pairs[k]` returns a list of rules for `g` and `n`, so W[g,n] does not know what are the values for them.

This definition solves your problem:

```
S[m_] := Total@(W[Sequence @@ #] & /@ ({g, n} /. pairs[m - 1]))
```

Comment: Thank you! But I don't quite understand the reason. Why shouldn't the replacement rule work? And why does it seems to work for all other values of g and n?

Comment: Because, `g` and `n` are variables of the function `W` not parts of an expression given by `W[g,n]`. On the other hand, what you mean with "all other values of g and n"?

Comment: I don't have a problem with my code for values other than (g,n) = (1,1) and (g,n) = (0,3). But I suppose that makes sense given what you just said, if a recursive function is interpreted as an expression for values other than the base case.